# main() program won't exit normally

Tags: c++11

My C++ 2011 main() program for DiGSE is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
. . .
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // this } DOES match the opening { above
```

It compiles and executes correctly. A print statement immediately before the return outputs normally.  However, a Windows 7.1 notification pops up saying "DiGSE.exe has stopped working."  It then graciously offers to search the web for a solution.

I tried replacing the return with return 0;  exit(0); and nothing so execution falls out the bottom (which, as I understand, is acceptable).  However, in all cases I still get the pop-up.

What do I do to get the main() to exit gracefully?

---

DiGSE is just the name of the Windows 7 executable compiled on MinGW 4.9.2.  The "full" program is already stripped down:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

try {
DiGSE::log_init(DiGSE::log_dest_T::console_dest, "dig.log", true,
                DiGSE::log_lvl_T::trace_lvl);
}//try

catch (const std::exception& ex) {
    std::cerr << FMSG("\n"
                      "Executing '%1%' raised this exception:\n"
                      "    %2%", % DiGSE::Partition::productName()
                      % ex.what())
              << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}//exception

catch (...) {
    std::cerr << FMSG("\n"
                      "Executing '%1%' instance raised an unknown exception.",

                      % DiGSE::Partition::productName())
               << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}//exception

L_INFO(FMSG("'%1% v%2%' terminated normally.", 
            % DiGSE::Partition::productName()
            % DiGSE::Partition::productVersion()))
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}//main()

The L_INFO() is a logging call, which outputs as it should.  The log_init() at the top initializes the log.  Commenting out log_init() and L_INFO() has the same result as originally reported.

---

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000006fc8da9d in libstdc++-6!_ZNSo6sentryC1ERSo ()
   from D:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-4.9.2-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev0\mingw64\bin
\libstdc++-6.dll

This is what gdb returns while mail() is exiting.  It does this even with the log_init() and L_LNFO() commented out.  So the problem is probably in one of globals of something it's linked to.

Comment: educate me...what's DiGSE? Is it some kind of special operating system or architecture? If so, you might have to read up on that, to see what value the operating system expect. If it's really weird, maybe it differs from 0 or the EXIT_SUCCESS macro

Comment: What's in the `...` part?

Comment: @HenrikKjusAlstad S/he explicitly states that `Windows 7.1` is the OS.

Comment: "It then graciously offers to search the web for a solution." LOL

Comment: Either the problem comes from the outside (the C++ runtime may be at fault), or you trashed your stack. Does an empty program work ? If so, try removing code until this one does.

Comment: There's a lot that happens between when `main` returns and when the process truly exits.  Destructors are called, DLLs are unloaded.  Any of these could cause abnormal process exit prior to normal process exit.  Have you tried attaching a debugger?

Comment: Is `DiGSE.exe` the executable for your program?

Answer (score 3):

It is completely possible for a program to crash after the end of `main` -- the program isn't over yet.  The following items execute after `main()` returns:

- Registered `at_exit` handlers
- Destructors for `main()`'s own automatic variables, and all variables with static storage duration (globals and function-static) (C++ only)
- `DllMain(PROCESS_DETACH)` code in all dynamic libraries you are using (Windows only)

In addition to that, various events can occur outside your program and cause failures which you might mistake for a failure of your program (especially if your program forks or spawns copies of itself):

- `SIGCHLD` is raised (on *nix).  Process handles become signaled and cause wait functions to return (on Windows)
- All open handles (file descriptors) get abandoned, and the `close` handler in the driver is invoked
- The other end of connections (pipes, sockets) shift into a disconnected state (reads return 0, writes fail, on *nix `SIGHUP` may be raised)

I suggest attaching a debugger, set a breakpoint at the end of main, and then single-step through the cleanup code to find out where the failure is occurring.  Divide and conquer may also be helpful (cut out some global variables, or all usage of a particular DLL).